# How many ways are there to cut a necklace (in th form of an unbroken circle) with $30$ pearls into $8$ parts (it is permitted in between pearls)?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to cut a necklace (in th form of an unbroken circle) with $30$ pearls into $8$  parts (it is permitted in between pearls)?

Well, my solution goes something like this :
We have to divide $30$ pearls into $8$ parts . We can represent this as $x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_8=30$ . Now each of these $8$ integers should be positive . So, we consider $x_i=x_i'+1$ for all $i\in{1,2,...,8}$ and $x_i'\geq 0$ . Now, substituting this values in the original equation we get, $x_1'+x_2'+...+x_8'=22$ . Now, the number of solutions of this equation is $29\choose 7$ . So, we can divide $30$ pearls into $8$ parts is  $29\choose 7$.

However, if we do it in this way :

> There are $30$ places for making the cut. We can choose $8$ places for it. So the total no. of ways is $30\choose 8$ .

However, both of them must be equivalent.Which method is valid? Why is the other one not valid? Where is the problem occuring?I am not getting it...

Comment: Depends what the question means.  For example, with your second method, cutting into pieces $1,2,3,4,1,2,3,14$ and $1,1,2,2,3,3,4,14$ would count as different results.  With your first method, they would be the same.

Comment: @David Thanks! So the first method should be taken valid "in general" isnt it ? Unless anything else is specified....

Comment: According to the first method there are $\binom21=2$ ways to cut a necklace with $3$ pearls into $2$ parts (how?...). According to the second there are $\binom32=3$ ways (seems fine).

Comment: @drhab well, that is what the thing is....in the 1st way the cut into two parts are:$(2,2)$ and $(1,2)$. But in the 2nd part :$(2,2),(1,2),(2,1) $ are the three possible cases as $ (1,2) $ and $(2,1) $ are  considered different . Whereas in 1st part they are the considered the same i.e $(1,2) $ and $(2,1)$ are considered same way of partitioning....

Comment: If the pearls are named $a,b,c$ then I discern $3$ possible split ups: $\{\{a\},\{b,c\}\},\{\{b\},\{a,c\}\},\{\{c\},\{a,b\}\}$. But the first method tells that there are only $2$. Then which one is not valid?.. I cannot find a legitimate answer on that, so tend to reject the first method.

Comment: @Franklin My point of view is that if nothing is specified, then you should go back to the person who asked the question and tell them that it is unanswerable because they have given insufficient information.  Without this, nobody can say whether the first method is valid or the second (or maybe something else).